# How can I make these two threads run one after the other constantly python?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, raspberry-pi, threadpool

so I have this code where I need these two threads to be run one after the other CONSTANTLY.

So, once thread 1 finishes, thread 2 goes and once thread 2 finishes, then thread 1 goes then thread 2 etc...like constantly as if it's an infinite loop.

```
import httplib, urllib
import time, sys
import serial
from threading import Thread
#from multiprocessing import Process

key = 'MY API KEY'    #API Key required for ThingSpeak.
rfWaterLevelVal = 0         #Global variable that holds the final water level value.

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)

#Gathers the rf data received and separated it to obtain the water level data.
def rfWaterLevel():
    global rfWaterLevelVal
    rfDataArray = ser.readline().strip().split()
    print 'incoming: %s' %rfDataArray
    if len(rfDataArray) == 5:
        rfWaterLevelVal = float(rfDataArray[4])
        print 'RFWater Level1: %.3f cm' % (rfWaterLevelVal)

#Created purely to making the multithreading easier.        
def rfWaterLevelFinal():
    while True:
        try:
            rfWaterLevel()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "caught keyboard interrupt"
            sys.exit()

#Sends the sensor data over to ThingSpeak.
def sendData():
    global rfWaterLevelVal

    params = urllib.urlencode({'field1':rfWaterLevelVal, 'key':key})
    headers = {"Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80", timeout = 5)
    conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.status, response.reason
    data = response.read()
    conn.close()

#Created purely to make multithreading easier.
def sendDataFinal():
    while True:
        try:
            sendDataFinal()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "caught keyboard interrupt"
            sys.exit()

#start thread 1 for rf water level data.
t1 = Thread(target = rfWaterLevelFinal())
t1.start()

#start thread 2 for sending the data.
t2 = Thread(target = sendDataFinal())
t2.start()

#wait for both threads to finish
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

So essentially I need this thread 1 start then finish, thread 2 start then finish, to be constantly run (as if it's in an infinite loop).

I have looked at using a threadpool for this in python but i have no clue how to apply it.

Any ideas on what I could do to get the results that I want?

Cheers
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you dont need thread to run sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you wanted,

```
while True:
    t1 = Thread(target = rfWaterLevelFinal())
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    t2 = Thread(target = sendDataFinal())
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

But no need to run like that with threads, you can just call the methods.

```
while True:
    rfWaterLevelFinal()
    sendDataFinal()
```

Comment: I kind of need to run them as a thread as the first methods needs to be run properly (as it receives rf data and if there is any delay during the process, it freezes/delays every other data)

Comment: anyway you have mentioned you need to wait till thread 1 finishes to start the thread 2. So above 2 options will work as such